# TYPO3 TypoScript CONTENT how to render select result

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

i have to render all results of the query, not just one. at the moment i only receive the first results of that query and the result stays the same for all 3 calls.

here is the template/partial which gets called for every page

```
<div class="item">
  <f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>
  <f:link.page pageUid="{page.data.uid}" target="{page.data.target}" title="{page.data.title}">
    <h3 class="title">{page.data.title}</h3>
    <h4>{page.data.uid}</h4>
    <h3><f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.category" data="{page.data}" /></h3>
  </f:link.page>
</div>
```

the important call is this one

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.category" data="{page.data}" />
```

here is the typoscript to get all the categories

```
lib.category = CONTENT
lib.category {
  table=sys_category
  wrap=|
  select {
    pidInList = root
    selectFields = sys_category.*
    join = sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = sys_category.uid
    where.field = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = uid
    languageField = 0
  }
  renderObj = COA_INT
  renderObj {
    1 = TEXT
    1.field = title
  }
}
```

the important line is:

```
where.field = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = uid
```

= uid is the uid we pass in <f:cObject...

and here the part which actually renders the string with the category title (just one at the moment...even if more categories are set)

```
  renderObj = COA_INT
  renderObj {
    1 = TEXT
    1.field = title
  }
```

so 2 problems:

1. for all pages we get the same category, even if they are not the same
2. only one category out of X gets rendered no matter what

how should i rework that typoscript/template to achive that i get a full list (can be a string) of assigned categories from that specific page?

help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you will need to write your own ViewHelper to do this. The default core "API" offers no support for categories. Also, it seems, this is not planned for the very useful [vhs extension](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/vhs/), as a [feature request for exactly this](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/vhs/issues/1607) has been closed.

Luckily, you can copy&paste a [solution from someone else](https://coding.musikinsnetz.de/typo3/fluid-viewhelpers/access-system-categories-in-content-elements-templates). The solution in fluid then looks like:

```
<f:if condition="{data.categories}">
    <f:for each="{my:CategoriesOutput(recUid: data.uid)}" as="category">
        <span class="{category.slug}">{category.title}</span>
    </f:for>
</f:if>
```